# Find the intersection of two dataframes and compute the average of an integer row in the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have two dataframes that contain `id`, `score`, and `studentName`.

I would like to create a dataframe that contains only `id`s that appear in **both** `test1` and `test2`. Then, I would like to average the students' scores.

Here is some sample data:

```
test1 <- data.frame(id = numeric(0), score = integer(0), studentName = character(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test1[1, ] <- c(1, 100, "Alice")
test1[2, ] <- c(2, 98, "Bob")
test1[3, ] <- c(3, 64, "Josh")
test1[4, ] <- c(4, 84, "Jake")

test2 <- data.frame(id = numeric(0), score = integer(0), studentName = character(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test2[1, ] <- c(1, 90, "Alice")
test2[2, ] <- c(2, 95, "Bob")
test2[3, ] <- c(3, 80, "Josh")
test2[4, ] <- c(10, 50, "Emma")
```

The output should be a dataframe that contains the following rows:

- (1, 95, "Alice")
- (2, 96.5, "Bob")
- (3, 72, "Jake")

Note that the student `id`s of `4` and `10` are omitted because they do not appear in both `test1` and `test2`.

I'm thinking about using an `apply` function with `intersection` and `mean`, but I'm not sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, you could use `merge` and `rowMeans` (assuming that the 
'score' column is 'numeric').

```
 res <- merge(test1, test2[-1], by='studentName')
 res
 #   studentName id score.x score.y
 #1       Alice  1     100      90
 #2         Bob  2      98      95
 #3        Josh  3      64      80
```

We are interested in averaging the rows of columns "score.x", and "score.y", which are the 3rd and 4th column in "res".  The `rowMeans` get the mean value of the rows of those columns (`rowMeans(res[,3:4])`).

```
 res$score <- rowMeans(res[,3:4])
```

If we don't need the "score.x" and "score.y", we can remove it by negative indexing `-c(3:4)` or `-(3:4)`

```
 res[-(3:4)]
 #   studentName id score
 #1       Alice  1  95.0
 #2         Bob  2  96.5
 #3        Josh  3  72.0
```

Comment: Would you edit your answer to explain the indexing? Like the res[,3:4] and res[-(3:4)] parts?

Comment: @user4605941 Sure, I will

Comment: @user4605941  Updated the post.  Please check if that helps

Answer (score 2):

Using `library(dplyr)`:

```
df <- inner_join(test1,test2[,-3],by="id")
df <- df %>% mutate(mean_score = (score.x + score.y)/2) %>% select(-c(score.x,score.y))
```

If you load the `magrittr` package you can simplify the second line using the %<>% operator:

```
df %<>% mutate(mean_score = (score.x + score.y)/2) %>% select(-c(score.x,score.y))
```